# How can I remove a site from a network?

Tags: multisite

I have a site inside a multi-site network. I would like to detach it and transform to a separate/independent site. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

By reading all that Ipstenu has published.

#### [Multisite 101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/) > Advanced Topics > Exporting a Site

> If you want to export one site from the network and install somewhere else, you will have to make a couple important decisions. If all you care about is the content, a traditional WordPress export will be just fine. You can simply import the content on the new location, be it a separate install of WordPress, or just a different site on your network.
>
> If you need to keep the look and feel of your site, all the plugins, theme settings, and users, it’s vastly more complicated. The basic steps would be to:

#### [Moving WordPress Multisite](http://halfelf.org/2012/moving-wordpress-multisite/)

> You’re going to have to do some work in the database, so now’s the time to get some coffee and practice not freaking out.